# How to work with wysiwyg generated code?

Tags: php, security, wysiwyg, html-entities

I want to use the same editor as SO has on a site of mine, the user should also be able to type code, which is stored in the database. But there's something I don't understand:

How do I make the difference between markup (p, strong, li)-tags and code that should be shown as code and not interpreted by the browser?

When I store the submitted data in the database, I'll call the htmlentities function, and this will affect every tag: markup generated wy the wmd editor, and also html code (or other language) posted by the user.

Any information on this please? I really have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: StackOverflow uses the backtick character or `<pre>` tags to make code that should be interpreted as code be interpreted as code. (the backtick is the key under `esc` on normal keyboards (UK layout)). I don't have any ideas beyond that though, hence why this is a comment not an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling htmlentities function when you store it in the database?

This is what breaks your markdown. I mean markup. Well, both actually.

Comment: How should I treat the code once I pull it out of the DB than? Keeping security in mind etc. ?

Comment: After you process it with Markdown you should sanitize it keeping only those HTML tags that you want to allow using, or encode the html entities before you display it as HTML, if what you want to display is the HTML source code. There is no point in html-encoding anything that goes into the database. The only time when it is useful is when you display the data literally in HTML.

Comment: I see, I had something totally wrong in my mind then. Any info on how I should distinguish the tags that I want to and code from the others? Really knew to this...

Comment: [Google for HTML Sanitization](http://www.google.com/search?q=HTML+Sanitization), there are a lot of resources on that topic. Generally when you put data into a database you have to worry about SQL injections first (if it's an SQL database), you might also sanitize your markdown and/or markup before you store it, but what you always have to do is to sanitize or html-encode everything that you are going to include in a web page to avoid cross-site scripting and similar vulnerabilities.